# Why igraph::cluster_walktrap gives a different result for non directed isomorphic graphs?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to use igraph::cluster_walktrap in R to look for communities inside of a graph, however I noticed a weird behaviour (or at least, a behaviour I am not able to explain).

Suppose you are given an undirected graph by defining a list of its edges. Say

```
a,b
c,d
e,f
...
```

Then, if I define another graph by swapping randomly selected vertices in the edge list definition:

```
a,b
d,c
e,f
...
```

I expect the two graphs to be isomorphic and the difference between the two graph to be empty. This is exactly what happens in R in my toy example. Following this line of reasoning, calling cluster_walktrap on the two graphs (using set.seed appropriately) should yield the same result since the two graphs are the same. This is not happening and the only explanation I can give is that the starting point of each random walk is not the same for the two graphs. Why is this?

You can follow my reasoning in the toy example below. I don't understand why the last two objects are not identical.

```
require(igraph)

# Number of vertices
verteces <- 50

# Swap randomly some elements in the edges definition
set.seed(20)
row_swapped <- sample(1:verteces,25,replace=F)
m_values <- sample(letters, verteces*2, replace=T) #1:100

# Build edge lists
m1 <- matrix(m_values, verteces, 2)
m1
a <- m1
colS <- seq(round(ncol(m1)*0.3))
m1[row_swapped, 2:1] <- m1[row_swapped, 1:2]
m1
b <- m1

# Define the two graphs
ag <- igraph::graph_from_edgelist(a, directed = F)
bg <- igraph::graph_from_edgelist(b, directed = F)

# Another way of building an isomorphic graph for testing
#bg <- permute(ag, sample(vcount(ag)))

# Should be empty: ok
difference(ag, bg)
# Should be TRUE: ok
isomorphic(ag,bg)
# I expect it to be TRUE but it isn't...
identical(ag, bg)

# Vertices
V(ag)
ag
V(bg)
bg

# Calculate community
set.seed(100)
ac1 <- cluster_walktrap(ag)
set.seed(100)
bc1 <- cluster_walktrap(bg)

# I expect all to be TRUE, however
# merges is different
# membership is different
# names are different

identical(ac1$merges, bc1$merges)
identical(ac1$modularity, bc1$modularity)
identical(ac1$membership, bc1$membership)
identical(ac1$names, bc1$names)
identical(ac1$vcount, bc1$vcount)
identical(ac1$algorithm, bc1$algorithm)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results are not different. You have two things going on which is making your graphs **not identical** but isoporphic. I emphasize identical because it has a very strict definition.

1) `identical(ag, bg)` is not identical because the vertices and edges are not in the same order between the two graphs. Exactly, the same nodes and edges exist but they are not in the exact same place or orientation. For, example if I shuffle the rows of `a` and make a new graph...

```
a1 <- a[sample(1:nrow(a)), ]
a1g <- igraph::graph_from_edgelist(a1, directed = F)
identical(ag, a1g)
#[1] FALSE
```

2) This goes for edges as well. An edge is stored as node1, node2 and a flag if the edge is directed or not. so when you swap rows the representation at the "byte level" (I use this term loosely) is different even though the relationship is the same. Edge 44 represents the same relationship but is stored based on how it was constructed.

```
E(ag)[44]
# + 1/50 edge from 6318240 (vertex names):
#   [1] q--d
E(bg)[44]
# + 1/50 edge from 38042e0 (vertex names):
#   [1] d--q
```

So onto your `cluster_walktrap`, first, the function returns the index of the vertices, not the name which can be misleading. Which means the reason the objects aren't **identical** is because `ag` and `bg` have different ordering of nodes in the object.
If I reorder the membership by node name the two become identical.

```
identical(membership(bc1)[order(names(membership(bc1)))], membership(ac1)[order(names(membership(ac1)))])
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: So, If I understand correctly, I can use the reordering to obtain the same result after calling cluster_walktrap? My goal is to obtain the same results after calling the cluster_walktrap on two undirected isomorphic graphs.

Comment: Yes, I would also suggest that you use igraph's accessor functions for these objects, e.g. `membership` instead of `ac1$memberships`

Comment: Thanks for the support! I already upvoted, I'll check tomorrow if I can solve my problem if yes I'll definitely accept your answer!

Comment: I accept your answer since it is exactly what I was asking. However it didn't solve my problem because the 2 graphs were not isomorphic in the first place (not really sure why since some couples of vertices have been swapped but the graphs are not directed, so...)

Comment: Your comment is confusing. In your post your example graphs are isomorphic, but they are not identical.

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry. I'm using this code in a work project on some data which I do not own so I cannot share it. On this data, I build undirected 2 graphs one of which is simply built by swapping some vertices in the definition. The two graphs should be isomorphic but they are not. This is what causing the problem. So my issue has not been solved but the question has.